# video editing (smooth) fast forward

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I'm using mainly blender for video editing usually, (and virtualdub).
(yes i know it takes a bit more time, but i prefer the finer blender control)
Recently I started to use 2.8 for video editing.
I kinda wonder how one might create a fast forward effect.
ea start at 30fps, then smoothly go to 90fps and smoothly back to 30 fps.
I have some footage that contains a bit boring period, (drone flight), but i cannot realy cut it out either (that brakes the flight route, i dont want that).

Comment: seams to be for a fixed speed ratio, i'd like to have a smooth curve based increase in fps

Comment: Sounds like you didn't read the related question, but I'll give you the benefit of the doubt. When you hover over a property in Blender, you can press ***I*** (i) to set a keyframe. You can set multiple keyframes on the speed factor property. E.g. (100, 1) and (120, 4). The speed will ramp up over the 20 frames. You can edit the resulting speed graph in the graph editor.